# three.js EdgesGeometry / Line Segments do not update after verticesNeedUpdate()

Tags: javascript, three.js

I created several three.js objects.

I noticed that 'other' objects designed as Mesh/Geometry/Material do update as expected after verticesNeedUpdate()

Additionally, I have two wireframe objects which I designed this way:

```
new THREE.LineSegments(new THREE.EdgesGeometry(new THREE.BoxGeometry(100,100,100), new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: 0xFF0000});
```

These objects do not update on verticesNeedUpdate(). My workaround right now is to delete them from scene and add them again on every change in the vertices, but I would like to perform this update more smart...

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. Do you expect that `THREE.LineSegments()` with `THREE.EdgesGeometry()` will change its vertices when you perform `.verticesNeedUpdate()` on `THREE.BoxGeometry()`?

Comment: Yes, thats what I thought it would. But if not, whats the best way to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the rest of your code, it's hard to say.. however.. I'd guess that you're not re-using the box geometry that you are changing.

Try to create your box geometry on a separate line to ensure you're only using one box geometry, and not creating a new one inside of Line Segments.

```
var boxGeo = new THREE.BoxGeometry(100,100,100);
var lineMat = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: 0xFF0000});
// use boxGeo in your other mesh
new THREE.LineSegments(new THREE.EdgesGeometry(boxGeo, lineMat));
```